# get coordinates of middle of items in recyclerView relative to parent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to find out the X,Y coordinates of Item in recycler view relative to parent, my items in recycler view has top padding and recycler view width is matchParent so the most important thing is to get the Y coordinates item in recycler View relative to parent.
Im using `LinearLayoutManager` for my recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You can get the View from `LinearLayoutManager` and then get x and y coordinates from `View` . Since your `RecyclerView` has padding it will give you coordinate including padding and that will be the actual coordinates of view start. You can try out the code below .

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =(LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(itemPosition);
    if(view!=null){
      float X = view.getX();
      float Y = view.getY();
    }
```

Comment: ok but I don't want the coordinate of view inside my recyclerView, I need coordinates according to my parent layout

Comment: Its better if you edit your question with more detail . Possible add a graphical representation of what you need . i can not understand . Also add the layout design what u have if your parent layout only have a recyclerView then Y will be same against parent or against recycler View . Have you tried `View.getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocationInWindow()`?